# Future perfect with passive and modal verbs

Tags: modal-verb, passive, future

Assuming we start with a sentence in the passive voice with a modal verb

> Das Auto muss morgen verkauft werden

Then we can form the future (*Futur I*)

> Das Auto wird morgen verkauft werden müssen

Then we can form the future perfect (*Futur II*)

> Das Auto wird übermorgen haben verkauft werden müssen

As far as I can tell this is correct, but it looks very strange. Does anybody actually use this kind of construction in real life (preferably with links to examples)?

EDIT:
Some commentators find the *haben* wrong. Here's a quote from Duden

> Bei Verbalkomplexen, die mehr als zwei infinite Verbformen (hier: Modalverb/Vollverb/Hilfsverb) enthalten, muss das Verb (="haben"), das den Ersatzinfinitiv des Modalverbs (="müssen") regiert, dem infiniten Vollverb (="verkauft werden") unmittelbar vorangehen …

Comment: Actually I would say: *Das Auto muss bis übermorgen verkauft **sein*** or *Das Auto wird bis übermorgen verkauft sein müssen* - but I have no idea about the rules behind this, and why your example appears to be wrong.

Comment: @Takkat Of course your suggestion is what any normal person would say in this situation. I'm testing the possibilities with *werden*

Comment: *Es wird bis übermorgen verkauft worden sein müssen* - as much as I turn this sentence, *haben* does not want to fit.

Comment: Das Auto wird übermorgen verkauft werden gemusst haben. I think that’s what you’re looking for, I am not saying that it’s actual German.

Comment: @PiedPiper, but I think my word order makes more sense than yours. Das Auto muss fahren -> Das Auto wird fahren gemusst haben. For sentences that make sense, choose Takkat’s.

Comment: @miep Even if we needed the auxiliary of *verkaufen* it would be *haben*: "ich **habe** das Auto verkauft". But we don't: we need the auxiliary of *müssen* which is also *haben*

Comment: Yes, my mistake. It's actually the werden which takes place when modal verbs are used. Which is, now that i think about it, very confusing if you're not used to it. So I understand your doubts

Answer (score 1):

> Das Auto wird übermorgen haben verkauft werden müssen

is not correct. "[...]übermorgen verkauft worden sein" or "Wir müssen das Auto bis übermorgen verkauft haben". I think your error in thinking is that you try to form the past from 'werden' with 'haben'. But 'werden' is future form of "sein", past form "war", and is formed with 'sein' and not with 'haben' in past and future forms:

"ich bin/war(from sein) gewesen(also from sein)"
There are several more words used with sein instead of haben:

- ich bin gelaufen
- ich bin gefallen
- ich bin verschwunden
- wir sind gegangen
- etc...

That's why the future also forms without "haben". -> "Das Auto wird übermorgen verkauft worden(from sein) sein(from sein)"

In contrast:

- ich habe gehabt
- wir haben gespielt
- sie haben geschrieben.

BUT: (future I is formed with werden)

- wir werden haben
- ich werde spielen
- sie werden schreiben

Futur II:

- wir werden gehabt haben
- ich werde gespielt haben
- sie werden geschrieben haben.

So even if the future is always formed with "werden", for future II the standard auxiliary verbs come in use.
Hope I could help.

EDIT:
When modal verbs are used, not the modal verbs will be changed but the main verbs. Which is in this case verkaufen.

Comment: But we need to form the perfect of *müssen* and not *werden*

Comment: no we don't. The problem here is, müssen is already a modal verb, so verkaufen is the verb you need to use.

Comment: "Er **hat** gehen müssen" and not "er ist gehen müssen". The modal verb defines the auxiliary verb

Comment: Yes, in past tense. In future with "werden" does this not apply. Also future II is nearly never used with modal verbs, due to the verbal clunkyness it produces.

Comment: And in the future: "Er wird haben gehen müssen". But I certainly agree with you that it's clunky. That's why I asked: is it **ever** used?

Comment: This sentence is also incorrect. And now that I'm thinking about it, it is never used. Because it doesn't exist. Sentences like that would be transformed in another form, as stated in other comments. I think the closest to what you ask for would be "Es muss übermorgen verkauft worden sein". The modal verb stays in present form, the rest will be "verkauft werden" which will become "verkauft worden sein". In this case its the "werden" from "verkauft werden" which is set in futur II.

Comment: It's good enough for Duden https://books.google.de/books?id=C59iDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA189

Comment: I stand corrected. touché. With this information, your initial example would form like this: "Das Auto wird übermorgen haben verkaufen müssen" Like this, the sentence doesn't really make sense, but it follows those rules. Btw, this Duden is 23 Years old. This grammatical structur is very rarely used (I'm a writer, and even I forgot that it existed), as there are more elegant and intuitive ways to express oneself.